# Is it possible to find a 2D distribution function such that the higher order moments always exist?

Tags: statistics, invariant-theory, invariance

Is it possible to generate a 2D distribution function $f(x,y)$ with function supports specified as $[-a,a]$ and $[-b,b]$ for $x$ and $y$ respectively, such that it always has moments which are NON ZERO up-to a certain higher order say $p+q$?

Comment: Question modified after an answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Every distribution whose suppport is bounded has moments of every order. Here, the support is included in $[-a,a]\times[-b,b]$ hence bounded.

If the support of the distribution is included in $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ with $0\lt a\lt b$ and $0\lt c\lt d$, then the $(i,j)$-moment is between $a^ic^j$ and $b^id^j$ for every nonnegative $i$ and $j$, in particular this moment is finite and positive.

Comment: And can we ensure those moments are always non-zero even if the support is possitive i.e., for the supports [a,b] and [c,d]?

Comment: Not sure I get your question but in any case see revised version.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But every distribution whose support is bounded has moments of every order might not be true. As an example, consider a distribution which is symmetric. In this case, some of the 3rd order moments become zero. Is it not?

Comment: Example (and objection) unrelated to my post. Would you be saying "to have moments of any order" to mean "to have moments of any order, whose values are not zero"?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. So i should have phrased it 'moments of any order, but non-zero. I ve edited the question.

Comment: And you should not have. Once a question is answered, if you have a different question, ask it as a new post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Moment Generating Function? Up to some conditions, i.e. when it exists, the MGF uniquely defines a distribution, by basically defining all its moments.